# How can I capture audio from a mic to send it over a socket?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, audio

I am using Windows 7 and developing a chat-like application with Visual Studio 2010. I am looking for an EASY way of capturing audio from a microphone (or rather, from the default recording device), collect the buffer from said input, and send it over a socket. I've seen DirectX solutions recommended, but from my research that is quite the opposite of simple. 5000 lines of sample code for a simple capture/save file program? That simply doesn't work for me (and yes, that was an official sample provided with the SDK).

Anyway, I don't need it to be cross-platform, and I would really prefer something that already comes with Windows, though I don't mind installing a library as long as it doesn't take longer than writing the hardware drivers from scratch to figure it out (exaggeration). I've heard of this waveInOpen function, but oddly enough I cannot find any demos on how to use it. If anyone has an idea or a link to some sample code, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks everyone for your time!

P.S. I can figure out the networking part myself. I just need access to the raw audio data buffer.

Comment: When you searched Google (or even Stack Overflow itself) for `waveInOpen`, what did you find?

Comment: The same thing I've been finding for the past 2 hours - questions and/or obvious facts. I need a demo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get PCM data from microphone in C++ (os Windows)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351659/how-to-get-pcm-data-from-microphone-in-c-os-windows)

Comment: Okay, thanks I think. I'll look over this code and see if I can find anything from it. Still seems a bit lengthy though. I use openCV for video and it's nowhere near as complicated as this audio stuff, heh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing the sockets yourself try checking out:

http://www.techmind.org/wave/

http://www.bcbjournal.com/articles/vol2/9810/Low-level_wave_audio__part_3.htm

http://www.relisoft.com/freeware/recorder.html

I enjoyed all of them but the last one, but then again, you might find it far more helpful.

Comment: So long as it's helpful... I was kinda worried since the only examples I had were in C or C++ since I really didn't have examples in any other language.