# C - how can I capture sound from the microphone?

Tags: c, winapi, audio, capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get PCM data from microphone in C++ (os Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351659/how-to-get-pcm-data-from-microphone-in-c-os-windows)

How can i capture sound from the microphone, and hear it in another computer live?
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you at least try to google this? At stackoverflow we help you solve a problem not design you a system.

Comment: I tried to use the WaveIn commands, but couldn't handle with them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452431.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The simplist way is to use the [waveIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452431.aspx) functions provided by the Win32 API.

You can read [Recording and Playing Sound with the Waveform Audio Interface](https://web.archive.org/web/20110324040408/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446573.aspx) for an overview, or just dive into the [API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940101.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To record, you can use the waveIn functions in win32API.

BUT before you send it, remember that the data got in the byte-buffer through waveIn function is PCM format, and it will easily clog your NETWORK. You must first compress the PCM data into aLaw or uLaw format before tunneling it through WinSOCK Apis. Otherwise, it will surely NOT be a "live" feed, also taking up a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: How can I compress the pcm data into aLaw or uLaw

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14237/Using-the-G711-standard see here for an open-source implementation. Although its in C#, it can be translated to C/C++

Answer (score 0):

Another easy solution for audio i/o is [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com). Aside from being portable, it's very easy to use.

To get audio data over the network, as another answer pointed out, you should be aware that your data is huge. However, a good place to start is to try sending raw data. Once you can do that, then you can worry about compressing it -- you need to solve a complex problem one step at a time. Eventually, you'll probably want to use UDP for the raw audio packets.

A good library for sending audio, video, chat and other data is google's [libjingle](https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/) which implements the google talk protocol. It has solved many of the issues with UDP vs TCP, firewalls etc. You may find it a bit hard to work with anyway as it's a lot of code and you'll need to work with XMPP which you may not be familiar with. Also, it's C++, not C. It also requires some server mediation, although you can use google's servers. If that doesn't work for you you can do something home grown but you may find you need to do a fair bit of work to get it all right.

I am sure there are some libraries to help you. Try googling for things like "internet telephony library c" and "voip c library" (even though this is not, in the strictest sense, voip)